# EmbeddedResource not working inside Target

Tags: msbuild, csproj

I have some TypescriptCompile files which I then want to embed in my .dll. I had to migrate to the new csproj format and now I can't embed while inside a Target.

This works:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
       <EmbeddedResource  Include="testFile.ts" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

While this does not:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <Target Name="AddGeneratedToBuildOutput" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
       <ItemGroup>
           <PackageFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.*;"/>
       </ItemGroup>
       <Message Text="The target is called: %(PackageFiles.FullPath)" Importance="high"/>
       <ItemGroup>
           <EmbeddedResource  Include="testFile.ts" />          
       </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Note that the message gets written and the referred file is in the project, hence we can be sure that the target gets called.

I already tried other targets instead of `CoreCompile` but since I'm using TypeScriptCompile, if I use `BeforeBuild`, `Build` or `ResolveReferences` I get compilation errors since the .js files are not generated yet.

I'm using JetBrains' DotPeek to inspect the resources and using msbuild 15.0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution to this problem is here: https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/4778